# Automated entry url numbering

Tags: url, url-title

OK, EE2 used to do this, but it looks like it has been abandoned by default in EE5.

Before, in EE2, if you put in two entries with the same title, EE would adjust the later one, adding a 1 or a 2 automatically if it spotted another entry that had the same title url. This was very handy for recurring events, like monthly board meetings.

ie,

```
/monthly-board-meeting
/monthly-board-meeting-1
/monthly-board-meeting-2
/monthly-board-meeting-3
```

The later ones would automatically add a number to avoid url conlicts. Is there a way to do that with EE5??

Answer (score 1):

This add-on [Willow-Smart-URL-Title](https://github.com/willowlight/Willow-Smart-URL-Title) will increment the url_title number (up to 10)